# Voltage sensing

Tags: voltage, adc, design

I have a system that needs voltage monitoring.

+12 Volt DC

-48 Volt DC (-54 Vdc)

The ADC chips I can find are limited with input voltage of max 5V.

Are there ADCs capable of doing the higher voltages?
What options do I have for level conditioning?  The obvious one is a voltage divider using high precision resistors.  What other more reliable methods are there?

Comment: What kind of precision do you need in your application?

Comment: Nothing more reliable than precision attenuation that I'm aware of for voltage measurement.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing unreliable about a voltage divider at those voltages, it is the standard method. The voltage regulators that maintain those voltages will have internal voltage dividers to compare the output voltage to a reference of less than 5V in almost all cases.

You probably do not really need 'high precision' resistors-- the tolerance on power supply rails is pretty sloppy in most cases. The ADC reference is part of the error budget so it needs to be as accurate as the resistors (give or take) or for the inaccuracy to be calibrated out, and stability has to be adequate for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Precision resistors are fine - think about when you have to use amplifiers and ask yourself which is the easier application - example below: -

An ADC, at the end of an amplifier chain is employed to measure the voltage from a thermocouple. The ADC might have an input range of 0 to 5V or 0 to 2.5V or +/-1V or several other standards. However, the thermocouple might only produce 40uV per degree centigrade (that'll be the K type thermocouple). At 1000 deg C it'll be producing about 40 milli-volt

Using a 5V input ADC means that the amplification needed for this range of temperature is 5V / 40 milli volts = 125 and the dc offsets have to be controlled rigorously to ensure accuracy throughout the range.

I'd much rather use a simple and accurate potential divider.